# Cannot authenticate to mongodb with mongoose without using admin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I can connect with RoboMongo and Studio 3T with no problem.

1. local mongo is running on my dev box

Works fine

```
return 'mongodb://:@localhost:27017/nodetodos';
```

2. **dev server mongo** is running on Linux on a Virtual machine

   ```
   return 'mongodb://root:bitnami@10.100.40.204:27017/nodetodos';
   ```

**That fails to authenticate! (nodetodos)**

**However, the admin database works, but that does not have my collections!**

```
return 'mongodb://root:bitnami@10.100.40.204:27017/admin';   (admin works)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the user is on the wole server
not on the nodetodos db

try use

```
return 'mongodb://root:bitnami@10.100.40.204:27017/nodetodos?authSource=admin';
```